# Jquery add commas to result field

Tags: jquery

So hoping to get some insight on this since I've been at it for hours with no luck

I've created 4 input fields the first three fields are multiplied for a total displayed on the final field. I was able to format the commas, get fields to multiply and generate a total. My problem is I cant get the form to display the commas on the 4th total field as seen below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated just dont know where I messed up also what could have I dont differently or better since I'm pretty new at this.

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    $("#result").val(val1 * val2 * val3);
  });
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.comma', function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="a">Number of people:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value1 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="a">Minutes Per Day:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value2 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="b">Number of Days:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value3 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="total">Total Minutes:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="result" />
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the desired output, and the output you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val().replace(/,/g, "");
    var total = (val1 * val2 * val3);
    $("#result").val(total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  });
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.comma', function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="a">Number of people:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value1 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="a">Minutes Per Day:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value2 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="b">Number of Days:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="input value3 comma" />
  <br>
  <label for="total">Total Minutes:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="result" />
</div>
```

You should apply your replace to total as well

Comment: Thank You guradio. Side note feeling really dumb right now as it was very obvious LOL...